# Nested functions - getting return value from one function in another

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

I have function that return source of image:

```
function addImg(img) {
...
return img.src;
}
```

and outside I have encapsulated function with variable **func** that creates new function and call **addImg(img)** function:

```
(function(obr) {
...

 var func = new Function ($(this).attr('onClick')); //it invoke addImage(img) function
     func();


})(this);
```

Code inside **addImg(img)** works fine, but nothing is getting back as a return value. **How to get back that return value ??** I know that's a new function so it can't return something from another function like that. I was trying different approaches with creating function **func**, but I was getting errors about "malformed formal parameter" or "too much recursion". **Is there a way to create a function to do that, or what can be a different approach to that problem ??**

Comment: How is addImage invoked?

Comment: Why are you dynamically generating a function from an `onclick` handler? Is there a reason you aren't just calling `addImg` directly?

Comment: "*`new Function ($(this).attr('onClick'));`*" - Shudder. Don't do that. Just call `this.onclick()` if you must.

Comment: addImage is in the beggining of the <srcript> tag and i want to invoke it inside my function.- Arun Ghosh

Comment: onclick handler is set to a button, and I want to get the body of addImg and especially it's return response in another function- Mike C